# i want ng-style set to an array to which has different index

Tags: html, angularjs, dynamic-arrays

Initially I set my **ng-style** to something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rowArray">
    <span ng-style="my_array[i]" >Some Text </span>
</div>
```

In the final i need something like,

```
<div> 
   <span ng-style="my_array[0]" >Some Text </span>
   <span ng-style="my_array[1]" >Some Text </span>
   <span ng-style="my_array[2]" >Some Text </span> 
</div>
```

So that i can change these styles in the **.js** file. 
How can i do this ?

Comment: use $index in ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

The thing you mention is entirely possible with the use of `$index`:

```
<ul ng-repeat="word in words">
  <li ng-style="styles[$index]">{{ word }}</li>
</ul>
```

And then:

```
 $scope.styles = [
    {
      color: 'red'
    },
    {
      color: 'blue'
    }
 ];
```

Will do just fine. Here is a plunkr for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/aNxWtmwkbklQUUtok62C